# Kotlin synthetic property difference for Android views?

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

The [Kotlin Android extension documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) says that you can basically do a shortcut of `findViewById()` by using an import statement. However, what is the difference between importing a specific view `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout-file-name>.<view-id>`and importing from `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout-file-name>.view.<view-id>`? If you do the former, the IDE shows me three of the same view ID, one each for Activity, Dialog, and Fragment. If you do the latter, it only shows the view ID name once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE hints show the class types you could use the view reference in: Activity, Fragment, Dialog or View. When you type the import statement, the IDE shows completion for all the types it is available for. However, when you try to use it inside the class (without the import statement), the IDE shows you the import hint for the specific type which your class is extending.

For instance, inside an activity class, extending `AppCompatActivity`, you get import hint

`<view-id> from <layout-file-name> for Activity`

However, if your class extends from `View` or subclasses, you get this:

`<view-id> from <layout-file-name> for View`

Regarding why there are multiple choices, the implementation of view caching could be different for different types. [More on this here](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)